# Angular-Dialog-Service and readability of modal code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm using the Angular Dialog Service to build pop up forms on my website. This services source can be found here: https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service/blob/master/README.md

Anyway, the actual angular and JavaScript that describes what the modal contains and does goes after the following where the ... is:

```
.run(['$templateCache',function($templateCache){
    $templateCache.put(...)
```

My problem is the html and js seem to have to all be one after the other with no spacing or indentation allowed between any of it. This causes the code that describes the modal to essentially just be a wall of text that has become borderline unreadable and editable in my complicated modal. An example of this can be found in the JS portion of the code here: http://codepen.io/m-e-conroy/pen/rkIqv

Is there an easy fix which will allow me to have my modals html and JS in non wall of text format and have it build successfully? If there is no fix this seems like a pretty big flaw in using the Angular Dialog Service to handle modals...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are tools, like [`html2js`](https://github.com/karlgoldstein/grunt-html2js), that can build templateCache for you.

It means, that you can store your html code in html files (where it obviously should be), and then gather it into single javascript file with `$templateCache.put(/* content of html file */);` in it. Just don't forget to include resulting module into your project, so when one of the services requested html file, it could be found in templateCache.

So you shouldn't edit html in .js files. It's wrong on many levels.